# How to change URL without refreshing the Whole Page?

Tags: angularjs, url, query-string, route-provider

I'm developing a site in angular and suppose I have navigated to iphone detail page and its current url is "localhost:8080/iphone/details" .
Now I have to implement a new functionality of applying coupons.In this suppose user clicks on some hyperlink from external site,
"localhost:8080/iphone/details?promotionalCode=12345"

User will land on that page(page will load after that modal will pop up) and a modal pop's up . And here details of promo code i will fetch from query parameter.

But my requirement is if i click cross (dismiss modal) ,and modal closes and state of url should be changed to localhost:8080/iphone/details .

What i have done till now .

I have used $location.search().promocode to fetch promocode if this is valid than modal will pop up and on dismiss modal i'm calling function in which i'm resetting state using $window.location.href , but this is making the whole page getting refreshed. Any suggestion on this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use `$location.search()`.

To get the query parameter `?promotionalCode=12345`, you will need to do `$location.search('promotionalCode',12345)`.

Please see: [AngularJS Documentation for `$location`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location)

Comment: Here my question is ,suppose user is on this URL "http://example.com/#/some/path?foo=bar" and a modal is there ,now on dismiss modal only modal should close and URL should be changed to "http://example.com/#/some/path" without getting the whole page reloaded .

Comment: @Aditya Looks like you want to clear the search. `$location.search({})` is what you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can use $stateProvider for this just give the state

```
    Example:   .state('app.page', {
            url: 'iphone/details',
            title: 'Coupon Applied', })
```